# base operand has non pointer type g++ compiler error

Tags: c++, c++11

In the following code, i am getting error:

```
city.cc: In member function ‘std::vector<std::basic_string<char> > MyCity::get_neighbours()’:
city.cc:25:42: error: base operand of ‘->’ has non-pointer type ‘std::pair<MyCity*, double>’
In file included from /depotbld/RHEL5.5/gcc-4.7.2/bin/../lib/gcc/x86_64-redhat-linux/4.7.2/../../../../include/c++/4.7.2/bits/stl_algobase.h:65:0,
                 from /depotbld/RHEL5.5/gcc-4.7.2/bin/../lib/gcc/x86_64-redhat-linux/4.7.2/../../../../include/c++/4.7.2/bits/char_traits.h:41,
                 from /depotbld/RHEL5.5/gcc-4.7.2/bin/../lib/gcc/x86_64-redhat-linux/4.7.2/../../../../include/c++/4.7.2/ios:41,
                 from /depotbld/RHEL5.5/gcc-4.7.2/bin/../lib/gcc/x86_64-redhat-linux/4.7.2/../../../../include/c++/4.7.2/ostream:40,
                 from /depotbld/RHEL5.5/gcc-4.7.2/bin/../lib/gcc/x86_64-redhat-linux/4.7.2/../../../../include/c++/4.7.2/iostream:40,
                 from city.cc:1:
/depotbld/RHEL5.5/gcc-4.7.2/bin/../lib/gcc/x86_64-redhat-linux/4.7.2/../../../../include/c++/4.7.2/bits/stl_pair.h: In instantiation of ‘std::pair<_T1, _T2>::pair(const std::pair<_U1, _U2>&) [with _U1 = std::basic_string<char>; _U2 = double; _T1 = MyCity*; _T2 = double]’:
city.cc:18:50:   required from here
/depotbld/RHEL5.5/gcc-4.7.2/bin/../lib/gcc/x86_64-redhat-linux/4.7.2/../../../../include/c++/4.7.2/bits/stl_pair.h:111:39: error: cannot convert ‘const std::basic_string<char>’ to ‘MyCity*’ in initialization
```

.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
#include <string>

using namespace std;

class MyCity {
string name;
std::vector<pair<MyCity*,double> > neighbours;
public:
MyCity()
{
   // neighbours.clear();
}
MyCity(string s, string s1, double d)
{
    name = s;
    neighbours.push_back(std::make_pair(s1,d));
}
std::vector<string> get_neighbours( )
{
    std::vector<string> names;
        for (size_t i = 0; i< neighbours.size(); ++i)
        {
        names.push_back(neighbours[i]->first->get_name());
    }
    return names;
}
};

class MyState {
vector<MyCity*> cities;
string name;
public:
MyState() { }
MyState(string s) {
    name =s;
}
bool add_city(string name, string neigh, double d)
{
    MyCity* c = new MyCity(name,neigh,d);
    cities.push_back(c);
    return true;
}
};
```

Comment: use neighbours[i].first

Comment: @AnatolyS but unless I'm much mistaken that's not the only error. In `neighbours.push_back(std::make_pair(s1,d));` the types are wrong too.

Comment: Read your error messages: `cannot convert ‘const std::basic_string’ to ‘MyCity*’ in initialization`. How do you think this is supposed to work? Please don't work with pointers! You clearly did not understand the concept yet, so be nice to yourself and stop worrying about it. Use objects only for a start.

Answer (score 1):

Do not dereference the `std::pair` as it is not a pointer.

```
std::vector<string> get_neighbours( )
{
    std::vector<string> names;

    for (size_t i = 0; i< neighbours.size(); ++i)
        names.push_back(neighbours[i].first->get_name());

    return names;
}
```

You also have a problem in your constructor, the `std::make_pair(s1, d)` will return a `std::pair<std::string, double>` so it cannot be pushed back to you neighbours vector.

Try something like that:

```
MyCtiy(string s)
    :name(s)
{
}

MyCity(string s, string s1, double d)
    :name(s)
{
    created_neighbours.emplace_back(new neighbour(s1));
    MyCity* city = created_neighbours.back().get();
    neighbours.push_back(std::make_pair(city, d));
    city->addNeighbour(this, d);
}

private:
std::vector<std::unique_ptr<MyCity>> created_neighbours;

void addNeighbour(MyCity* city, double d)
{
    neighbours.push_back(std::make_pair(city, d));
}
```

Note: you can strip the addNeighbourd part if you don't want the association to be many-to-many.

Edit: Fix the addNeighbour to give a MyCity pointer. Created a created_neighbours collection to store (and free) created neighbours.

Answer (score 0):

3 mistakes can be found in your code. Please find and correct the following 2 lines in your code

```
neighbours.push_back(std::make_pair(some_pointer_to_the_MyCity_object,d));

names.push_back(neighbours[i].first->get_name());
```

And you have to implement the get_name() function in MyCity class

Now it should be compiled